# Volume of ellipsoid proportional to inverse of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, conic-sections, volume

In a book on convex optimization it is said that if an ellipsoid is defined as

$$\mathcal{E} =\{v:\|Av-b\|_2\le 1\}$$

with $A\in S^n, A \succ 0$ ($A$ is a positive definite matrix and $b$ is a real vector),  $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the volume of the ellipsoid is proportional to $\det A^{-1}$. However, I know that the volume of an ellipsoid is proportional to $\det A$, not its inverse. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems to me that neither is true. The determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues, and the latter are the inverse squares of the ellipsoid’s semiaxis lengths.

Comment: The larger $A$, the smaller the volume. So I do not see why you think the volume is proportional to det A.

Comment: @LinAlg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711410/volume-of-ellipsoid-using-linear-algebra

Comment: @sequence The answer depends on the description of the ellipsoid. How do $a,b,c$ relate to $A$? I hope you agree that the set $\{x : |ax - 0| \leq 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ gets smaller as $a$ gets bigger.

Comment: @LinAlg Do you mean that this set contains less elements $x$ for bigger $a$?